# Search keywords in a string, get keyword locations and frequency

Tags: php

I really need help!

I should create a form with a text field where the user can enter a number of words separated by spaces.
Then i should create another textfield where the user can enter a keyword.
Then a button that when you click on it.

It should:

- Retrieves the string with words from the text field and from the outside it generates an array where each word ends up in its own place in the array. Prints the array of words in raw format with the print_r function.

""
**Loops through the array and uses an if statement to compare the keyword with each word in the array. If the word in the array is equal to the keyword, print the place where the keyword was found.
Also print how many times the keyword was found in the array..** ""

This last part im having trouble with...

My code so far:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    
<body>


  <html>
   <head>
      <title>Formular</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
       
    <p>Write in words.</p>
       
    <form action="" method="POST">
         <input type="text" name="word" value=""><br>
        <input type="text" name="sWord" value=""><br>
         <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
       
  <?php
       
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
                 
                 {

         $word = explode(' ', $_POST['ord']);
         $sWord = $_POST['sWord'];
        $sWord = array_count_values($word);
       
     
       
         echo "Words " .$_POST['word']. '<br />';
         print_r($word);
      
       
            printf($_POST['sWord']);
              }
         

       
      ?>
             
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: `explode(' ', $_POST['ord']);` - you intended `$_POST['word']`

Comment: OP: *"If the word in the array is equal to the keyword, print the place where the keyword was found."* ... How should the place(s) of the matched keyword(s) in the source string be indicated? As character offset, as nth word, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple question actually, this will get you far enough :D

```
$piecesArr = explode(" ", "hello my name is el chapo"); //space delimiter

foreach ($piecesArr as $singlePiece) {
    if($singlePiece === "name"){
         echo "We found name!"
     }
}
```

If you want to add button that retrieves that text live on page, then use javascript instead of php. take `inputTextbox.value.split(" ")`.....yadayada same process then as php

---- Edit ---

Basically php is a way to render any frontend content.
So if you want to use php to write javascript you would do it like this

```
<?php

$a = "random variable in php";
?>

<div>
    Same php file but now im writing in regular html
</div>

names:
<input id="myTextInput" type="text">
<button id="myButton">Click me for cool stuff</button>
<script>
    var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton"); 
    var myTextInput = document.getElementById("myTextInput"); 
    myButton.onclick = () => {
        var yourWantedArray = myTextInput.value.split(" "); //spaces
        if(yourWantedArray.length == 1 && yourWantedArray[0] == ""){
            alert("Enter something in the textbox...");
            return;
        }
        for(var i=0;i<yourWantedArray.length; i++){
            alert("word: " + yourWantedArray[i] + " is at index "+ i.toString() + " in your array/textbox...");
        }
    }
</script>
```

the code above was coded in a .php file. Cool huh!

Comment: Thank you! 
But i still dont understand. How can i get how many matches and where they lay in the array. I can only use php.

Comment: @LLKnow check out the code below edited :D